# In R, how do I set an S4 class based on another object's class

Tags: r, r-s4, bioconductor

I need to create an object of type ShortReadQ from Bioconductor's ShortRead library.

```
ShortReadQ 'signature(sread = "DNAStringSet", quality =
          "QualityScore", id = "BStringSet")'
```

The quality slot needs to be an object inheriting from QualityScore, of which I can easily determine from another ShortReadQ object that I wish to emulate.

```
> class(quality(anotherObject))
[1] "SFastqQuality"
attr(,"package")
[1] "ShortRead"
```

What is the best way to use that information ("SFastqQuality") in the contructor argument?

```
newObject<-ShortReadQ(sread=...,
             quality=SFastqQuality(...), 
             id=...)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You may either want to try to clarify your question further, or try bioconductor help: http://www.bioconductor.org/docs/postingGuide.html.

Comment: I want to get the classname of a given object and use that in the constructor of a new object.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your responses. they lead me to a solution that works

```
newObject<-ShortReadQ(sread=...,
             quality=new(Class=class(quality(anotherObject)),theFirstParameter=...), 
             id=...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
quality = new(class(old.quality.obj)[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want the get function:

```
a <- get(class(object))
a(...)
```